# Non repeating random numbers in C++

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I need to create an array that has a shorter length than the numbers' range that I have to choose among.
In the example I have an array made by 10 int and the range is between 20 and 50.
That means that most of the asnwers (found on various websites) to this question ("use the shuffle algoritm") couldn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

const int N = 10;
int arr[N];

srand(time(0));

// Just creates the array, but with repetitions
// for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
//     arr[i] = (rand()%31)+20;
//     }

for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
    bool valid = true;
    do {
        arr[i] = ((rand()%31)+20);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                valid = false;
            else
                valid = true;
        }
    } while(!valid);
}
```

With the "else" I check the previous value and, if it's the same, it's changed.
But if the same numbers are more far than just the previous one, this algoritm doesn't change the last one because the "else" of a previous right number ends the while.
If I remove the else, I remain stuck in the cicle, changing every time the number.

Comment: Still works: Work your way down the list until you have all the random numbers you need.

Comment: If I understand the question: I'd use a set and insert all the numbers into it (it will fail if the value is already there), Then convert the set to an array at the end.

Comment: An alternative is to create an array with the values 20..50 in it (or whatever limits) then shuffle that array and take the first 10 items from it.

Comment: Another alternative is to use the technique for selecting N random lines from a file while reading the file in one pass: http://stackoverflow.com/a/779867/12711  Just adapt that to "reading" a list of integers 20..50 instead of lines from a file.

Comment: Third alternative: create an array that contains the set of items to select from (20..50), chose one of those elements randomly and *remove* it from the array - don't just copy the item. Then choose the next item in the same way (taking into account that the array is now smaller), etc. until you have selected the number of items you want. The first alternative I suggested and this alternative mimic some of the common ways that people chose a random subset of things from a larger set (such as playing cards) in real life.